# Converting from a char to a long

Tags: java, arrays, long-integer, biginteger

I'm creating a big integer class. I read in two longs as function arguments and what I want to do is have each number in the long read in to occupy one index of an array.

I've done this by converting the long into a string then char array and storing them somewhere temporarily. This works fine and when printed out prints out exactly like the number read in. Now what I want to do is add them now to a new array and have their data type as `long`. I have made two arrays to deal with this.

Problem is when I try cast the char to a long, it gives me a completely different value. It seems that it's converting the char into it's own respective number? Character class doesn't seem to have any way of converting to a long.

What's the best way to do this?

EDIT: It seems that if I change the long arrays to int arrays and then use Character.getNumericValue(char ch) it works adding it to the array properly.

Since I'm planning to be returning a long at the end of this function should I make sure that those arrays are long for safety? Or storing them as ints in the array is fine? Thanks

```
public static long hugeMultiplication(long value1, long value2){
    System.out.println("originalvalue: "+value1);
    int lengthOfWordOne = String.valueOf(value1).length();
    int lengthOfWordTwo = String.valueOf(value1).length();
    System.out.println("length1: "+lengthOfWordOne);
    System.out.println("length2: "+lengthOfWordTwo);

    long[] numberOne = new long[lengthOfWordOne+1];
    long[] numberTwo = new long[lengthOfWordTwo+1];

    //make those longs into string to convert char array
    char[] tempValueOne = String.valueOf(value1).toCharArray();
    char[] tempValueTwo = String.valueOf(value2).toCharArray();

    //copy each value of a char array to long array and change to long again
    //this will set up the array having each number in it so we can do the multiplication
    for (int i = 0; i < tempValueOne.length; i++){
        numberOne[i] = (long) tempValueOne[i];
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < numberOne.length; i++){
        System.out.print(numberOne[i]);
    }
```

Comment: lengthOfWordTwo uses value1 instead of value2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only real difference between a `char` and a `long` is the data size. A `char` is typically 1 byte, while a `long` is typically 8 bytes. When you convert a `long` to a `string`, you are creating an array of ASCII characters that would represent this number. For example, the `long` 12345 would be represented in memory as:

```
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00110000 00111001
```

But when converted to a `string` (an array of 1-byte `char`s), it would look more like this:

```
00110001 00110010 00110011 00110100 00110101
```

Where each byte is a character in the string. The first byte being an ASCII '1', '2', etc.

When you cast each `char` back to a `long`, you are actually getting the ASCII value of each character in the string. So the `char` '1' is actually represented in memory as an integer 49, '2' is '50', and so on. What you will need to do is convert the string as a whole back to the integer representation.

Answer (score 8):

`long one = Character.getNumericValue('1');`

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#getNumericValue%28char%29

Comment: Excellent. If you want to be a little more strict, you can do new Long(Character.getNumericValue('1'));